# Visual Basic - What have I done wrong?

Tags: vb.net-2010

I am making a maze game and I have set the lives to 5. As always at the top of the form I have:

`Dim lives As Integer = 5`

further down the form I have made it so that when the user hits the boundary the picture box moves back to it's starting location and one life is deducted. However this all works apart from when the first initial life is lost it minuses 2 lives instead of 1. The code I have used is this:

```
Private Sub PictureBoxPlayer_move(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBoxPlayer.Move
    If PictureBoxPlayer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(PictureBoxWall12.Bounds) Then
        PictureBoxPlayer.Location = New Point(44, 503)
        lives -= 1
        LabelLives.Text = lives
        End If
    If PictureBoxPlayer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(PictureBoxWall11.Bounds) Then
       PictureBoxPlayer.Location = New Point(44, 503)
        lives -= 1
        LabelLives.Text = lives
    End If
    If PictureBoxPlayer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(PictureBoxWall9.Bounds) Then
        PictureBoxPlayer.Location = New Point(44, 503)
        lives -= 1
        LabelLives.Text = lives
    End If
    If PictureBoxPlayer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(PictureBoxWall8.Bounds) Then
        PictureBoxPlayer.Location = New Point(44, 503)
        lives -= 1
        LabelLives.Text = lives
    End If
    If PictureBoxPlayer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(PictureBoxWall7.Bounds) Then
        PictureBoxPlayer.Location = New Point(44, 503)
        lives -= 1
        LabelLives.Text = lives
    End If
    If PictureBoxPlayer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(PictureBoxWall6.Bounds) Then
        PictureBoxPlayer.Location = New Point(44, 503)
        lives -= 1
        LabelLives.Text = lives
    End If
    If PictureBoxPlayer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(PictureBoxWall5.Bounds) Then
        PictureBoxPlayer.Location = New Point(44, 503)
        lives -= 1
        LabelLives.Text = lives
    End If
    If PictureBoxPlayer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(PictureBoxWall4.Bounds) Then
        PictureBoxPlayer.Location = New Point(44, 503)
        lives -= 1
        LabelLives.Text = lives
    End If
    If PictureBoxPlayer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(PictureBoxWall3.Bounds) Then
        PictureBoxPlayer.Location = New Point(44, 503)
        lives -= 1
        LabelLives.Text = lives
    End If
    If PictureBoxPlayer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(PictureBoxWall2.Bounds) Then
        PictureBoxPlayer.Location = New Point(44, 503)
        lives -= 1
        LabelLives.Text = lives
    End If
    If PictureBoxPlayer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(PictureBoxWall1.Bounds) Then
        PictureBoxPlayer.Location = New Point(44, 503)
        lives -= 1
        LabelLives.Text = lives
    End If
    End Sub
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: You're mixxing PictureBoxWall10, looks like, on top of everything else...

Comment: Oh that's because I haven't renamed some of them. I did it in a weird way. There isn't a picture box 10.

Comment: I would set a breakpoint within each if statement and view the value of the lives variable each time a breakpoint is hit.

Comment: I would also add ' Return ' at the end of each 'if' block, so that it does not execute later 'if' blocks if the first intersection is found.

Comment: Or more simply, you could use ElseIf so it does not run later if blocks. - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Hmm, I still can't get it to work. It works great besides the first life goes down by 2 not one, the rest go down by one.